# Where to add a comparison counter in a merge sort implementation?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have the below implementation of merge sort. Now I would like to add a counter to find the number of comparisons made during the process, but I don't really know where I should start.

Where should I calculate the number of times the numbers get compared?

```
def mergesorter(A):
    if len(A) > 1:
        mid = len(A) // 2
        left = A[:mid]
        right = A[mid:]

        # Recursive call on each half
        mergesorter(left)
        mergesorter(right)

        # Two iterators for traversing the two halves
        i = 0
        j = 0
        
        # Iterator for the main list
        k = 0
        
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
              # The value from the left half has been used
              A[k] = left[i]
              # Move the iterator forward
              i += 1
            else:
                A[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            # Move to the next slot
            k += 1

        # For all the remaining values
        while i < len(left):
            A[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(right):
            A[k]=right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
```

Comment: I think the term *comparisons* is quite clear,  @Muhteva: swaps are different operations than comparisons. Comparisons are tests to see whether one item is greater than, or less than, or equal to, another item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your function currently has no return value, you could use that for returning the comparison count, and add those that you get back from recursive calls.

Note that when one speaks of counting *comparisons* in a sorting algorithm, then typically only the *data* comparisons are intended -- not the *moves*, nor the index comparisons.

There is only one spot in your code where *values* of the list are compared, so that is where you increment the count:

```
def mergesorter(A):
    if len(A) <= 1:
        return 0
    mid = len(A) // 2
    left = A[:mid]
    right = A[mid:]

    # Recursive call on each half
    comparecount = mergesorter(left) + mergesorter(right)

    # Two iterators for traversing the two halves
    i = 0
    j = 0
    
    # Iterator for the main list
    k = 0
    
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        comparecount += 1
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            # The value from the left half has been used
            A[k] = left[i]
            # Move the iterator forward
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        # Move to the next slot
        k += 1

    # For all the remaining values
    while i < len(left):
        A[k] = left[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len(right):
        A[k]=right[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

    return comparecount
```

Example run:

```
a = [5, 2, 8, 6, 9, 1, 3, 7, 0, 4]
comparecount = mergesorter(a)
print(a)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(comparecount)  # 21
```